# How to read/write to file that has only root access on Android?

Tags: android

I have a file `/sys/something`. And it's owned by `root:root` and has access level `444`.

How can I read and write to the file `/sys/something` in an android app?

If I change permission of the file, it resets back to the original permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create root process using:

`Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`

This process will emulate terminal. You can try to edit file using vim or nano and save it.

I am pretty sure that there is a way to get file stream out of that process, but need to recall how to do that.